# Send file with a json request

Tags: python, json, python-requests

i am trying to send to a webpage a file with a textmessage, but i have a problem with sending the file to the server. The textmessage isn't a problem

Update extra code with login to test it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.set_user_agent(
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36')

base_url = 'https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/'


def login():
    a = browser.open('https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/m-einloggen.html')
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.select_form('#login-form')
    browser['loginMail'] = 'testaccount@8.dnsabr.com'
    browser['password'] = 'testaccount'
    csrf_token = a.soup.find('input', {'name': '_csrf'})['value']
    print('crsf', csrf_token)
    browser.submit_selected()

    response = str(browser.get_current_page())
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

    if 'angemeldet als:' in str(soup.find('span', {'id': 'user-email'})):
        print('Erfolgreich eingeloggt!')
        return csrf_token
    else:
        a = soup.find('div', {'class': 'outcomebox-warning l-container-row'})
        a = a.findNext('h2')
        print('ERROR:', a.contents[0])
        return False


crsf = login()



headers = {
    "accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
    "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
    "x-csrf-token": crsf,
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "origin": "https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de",
    "referer": "https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/m-nachrichten.html"
}

img_file = open('img.jpg', 'rb')

file = {'contents': img_file, 'filename': 'name.jpg', 'format': 'image/jpeg'}

payload = {
    'id': "8td:32br0sx:2ck88rzjt",
    'message': 'message'
}

res = browser.post('https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/m-nachricht-schreiben.json', json=payload, headers=headers, files=file)
```

I am getting only a 500 response code, the message and the image file aren't send.

Here is the post request from the browser:
[image: postdata]

Answer (score 2):

Exactly, in `requests.post('https://www.url.json', payload, headers=headers, files=file)`, `payload` is a string because `json.dumps` returns a string here:

```
payload = json.dumps(
    {
        'id': "ID",
        'message': 'message',
        'image': []
    }
)
```

You should pass the dictionary itself:

```
requests.post('https://www.url.json', {'id': "ID", 'message': 'message'}, headers=headers, files=file)
```

Comment: This is a server-side error, it means that either you're passing the wrong data to the server or the server is misconfigured. If you're using some API, make sure you've reads its documentation and are following it exactly.

Comment: but i am also getting this error if i am not send the image file. This is not a API, this is: https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de

Comment: Then you may be sending the wrong data, using the wrong method, POSTing to the wrong URL - there may be lots of possible causes

Comment: I have update the question, with the full code. Could you maybe have a look at it?

Comment: Are you still getting the `ValueError`, as the question says?

Comment: In that case, you've just replaced the original question with a completely new one, where the issue is now caused by something else, so that now none of the answers make any sense because they're trying to solve the _original_ problem. Please revert your edits and ask a separate question

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the json.dumps! The payload should be a dict and not a string! So just try to remove that call.

Comment: if i am not using the json.dumps method i am getting a 500 error.

Comment: So that is the answer of your web server! Your request seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check the API specifications for what you should be sending. The header says you will be sending form-data, so I expect that the json payload (a string) should be encoded as the value of some parameter; it might be that you need something like this:

```
payload = json.dumps(some_dict)
requests.post('https://www.url.json', data={ 'textmessage': payload }, headers=headers, files=file)
```

Your api documentation will tell you what key name you need instead of `textmessage`. Or it might be that some other adjustment is needed. It's pretty hard to say without knowing what the API expects.